# Im trying to create a sign up page. Getting blank screen

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to create a sign up page. I followed a guide but its erroring and im presented with a blank screen when i run it. I think i may of misunderstood some code. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

        if (isset($_POST['register'])){
            if (empty($_POST['email']) &&
                (empty($_POST['username']) &&
                (empty($_POST['password']) &&
                (empty($_POST['re-enter']) &&
                (empty($_POST['title']) &&
                (empty($_POST['first name']) &&
                (empty($_POST['second name']) &&
                (empty($_POST['address']) &&
                (empty($_POST['postcode']) &&
                (empty($_POST['contactnumber'])){
                    $email=$_POST['email'];
                    $username=$_POST['username'];
                    $password=$_POST[['password'];
                    $reenter=$_POST['re-enter'];
                    $title=$_POST['title'];
                    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
                    $secondname=$_POST['secondname'];
                    $address=$_POST['address'];
                    $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
                    $contactnum=$_POST['contactnumber'];
                    if ($password == $reenter) {
                        $conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'i7266***', 'Winter****', 'i72*****');
                        $emailquery = "SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE email = '$email'";
                        $r = mysqli_query($conn, $emailquery);
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($r);
                            if ($count == 1) {
                                echo "Email already exists";
                            } else {
                                $query = "INSERT INTO UserTable VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$title', '$firstname', '$secondname', '$address', '$postcode', '$contactnum')";
                                $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                                echo "Customer account has been created";
                            }
                    } else {
                    echo "Passwords did not match";
                    } 
            } else {
                echo "please enter your details to register";
                }


        }else {
            echo "Please enter details to register";
            }



    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    Email:
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    Re-enter password:
    <input type="password" name="re-enter"><br>
    Title:
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Second name:
    <input type="text" name="secondname"><br>
    Address
    <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    Postcode:
    <input type="text" name="postcode"><br>
    Contact number
    <input type="number" name="contactnumber"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Try to check your code with `php -l your_filename.php`

Comment: Count the number of `(`. Then count the number of `)`. That ain't right. Not to mention, you are processing the form *only* if *ALL* of them *ARE empty*.

Comment: and use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: wow quick responses thankyou. Im newbie to this. I dont think i can get error messages as i am using the server given to me by the university which doesnt have it enabled i believe

Comment: Every newbie should start by learning basic debugging techniques. The very first one is to comment out all code untill something works. Then uncomment line by line, one at a time and echo out values you are not sure about.

Comment: Another great help is using text editor/ IDE with syntax highlighting. That will quickly expose dumb spelling mistakes and such. Some IDEs even have code inspections that will highlight 90% of newbie related stuff

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the '( )' in the second if in all the evaluations and you have one more of this '[' in `$password=$_POST[['password']`;

Try this:

```
<?php

        if (isset($_POST['register'])){
            if ((empty($_POST['email'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['username'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['password'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['re-enter'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['title'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['first name'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['second name'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['address'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['postcode'])) &&
                (empty($_POST['contactnumber']))){
                    $email=$_POST['email'];
                    $username=$_POST['username'];
                    $password=$_POST['password'];
                    $reenter=$_POST['re-enter'];
                    $title=$_POST['title'];
                    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
                    $secondname=$_POST['secondname'];
                    $address=$_POST['address'];
                    $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
                    $contactnum=$_POST['contactnumber'];
                    if ($password == $reenter) {
                        $conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'i7266***', 'Winter****', 'i72*****');
                        $emailquery = "SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE email = '$email'";
                        $r = mysqli_query($conn, $emailquery);
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($r);
                            if ($count == 1) {
                                echo "Email already exists";
                            } else {
                                $query = "INSERT INTO UserTable VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$title', '$firstname', '$secondname', '$address', '$postcode', '$contactnum')";
                                $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                                echo "Customer account has been created";
                            }
                    } else {
                    echo "Passwords did not match";
                    } 
            } else {
                echo "please enter your details to register";
                }


        }else {
            echo "Please enter details to register";
            }



    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    Email:
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    Re-enter password:
    <input type="password" name="re-enter"><br>
    Title:
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Second name:
    <input type="text" name="secondname"><br>
    Address
    <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    Postcode:
    <input type="text" name="postcode"><br>
    Contact number
    <input type="number" name="contactnumber"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
```

Hope works for you.

The syntax are fine now but the logic is wrong, as @Niet the Dark Absol says: You are processing the form only if ALL of them ARE empty.

Comment: Good catch on the `$password=$_POST[['password']` - that one escaped me.

Comment: Omg i thought i checked for those i need more sleep. ill try the code now thankyou! edit: Just ran the code and it displays now! thanks! doesnt fully work but its a start. Appreciate the help

Comment: @AidanClifford Did you read [Niet's comment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295803/im-trying-to-create-a-sign-up-page-getting-blank-screen#comment43056115_27295803)

Comment: I dont get the second part of the comment. I think i dont understand that part of the code fully.                                         if (isset($_POST['register'])){
            if ((empty($_POST['email']))                         could someone explain

Comment: In the second if, says if $_POST['email'] is empty and $_POST['username'] is empty and all the other variables are empty do.

Comment: All of the `empty` should be changed to `!empty`, that's why. OP needs to check if fields are "not" empty. ;)

Comment: @AidanClifford Read my above comment ^^^